# Mysterious time-travellers

Tags: wordplay

Yesterday, you had the concrete poured for your new patio, but during the night, some visitors came by and scrawled some words onto the setting concrete. Here are the words:

```
- Groundhog's green ball
- Esau and his nephew
- The great pork dinner
- Bond cat
```

Who are these four men?

Hint:

> These only have to do with the people's names, not what they have done and they are from the past.

Comment: Out of interest, are they all linked in some way?

Comment: @hexomino Yes, they are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Woodrow Wilson, because a synonym for groundhog is woodchuck and Wilson is a brand of tennis ball
>  2. Benjamin Harrison
>  3. ?
>  4. James Garfield

Still getting used to some of this stuff...

3 is really difficult but I will take a stab at it because I think I know how they relate

> Alexander Hamilton, a ton of ham?  Haha.   As for how they relate, I think they must have mailed themselves to the future ;)

Comment: You are indeed correct. "The great" part comes from the Greek of the first name, if you were wondering.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that they are (a similar line of thinking to Rip Tide)

> Former US presidents

- Groundhog's green ball

  > I think that this is **George W Bush**. 
  > Groundhog refers to Groundhog Day (as in the recurrence of another George Bush) and a bush is usually green. Also, the green ball in snooker is worth three and this is the third occasion where a direct descendent of a former US president was also US president (John Quincy Adams and Benjamin Harrison being the others). Also, an anagram of the hint is "George Bush, lorn gland", an unflattering description.
- Esau and his nephew

  > Esau has nephew 'Benjamin'. The origin of the name Esau is 'Hairy' and he was the first son of Isaac so it could be Benjamin Hairy-son = **Benjamin Harrison**
- The great pork dinner

  > **Abraham Lincoln** is known as 'The Great Emancipator'. Also his name contains 'ham' and 'Lincoln' which is known for its pork sausages.
- Bond cat

  > **James Garfield** for James Bond and Garfield the cat.

Comment: #3 was actually not a president. #1 needs a little more going into the synonym direction to find the name.

Comment: Okay I'll rethink #1. What do you mean about #3? He definitely, definitely was.

Comment: Like #3 as I intended originally was not a president.

Comment: Oh, I see. Okay, will rethink.

Comment: I like your explanation for #3 better than the intended one as it covers more of the name.